# mount error(13): Permission denied with windows share

Tags: linux, centos, samba, cifs

I am struggling to mount a windows 2008 share on a CentOS 6.4 (64 bits) server

when I use smbclient it works:

```
smbclient  //esb.local/dfs -U ESBSertal -W ESB -P MyPassword
```

but with mount it does not. I tried on the command line:

```
mount.cifs //esb.local/dfs -o username=ESBSertal,password=MyPassword,domain=ESB /mnt/win
```

and adding a line to /etc/fstab

```
//esb.local/dfs /mnt/win cifs username=ESBSertal,password=MyPassword,domain=ESB 0 0
```

in both cases I get the same error:

```
mount.cifs //esb.local/dfs -o username=ESBSertal,password=MyPassword,domain=ESB /mnt/win
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

and for fstab

```
mount -a
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I am grateful for your support.

just an update: this is executed as root. neither as root nor sudo work

Micha

Comment: What kernel version you are using on CentOS ?

Comment: here ist the full output from cat /etc/*release*
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
cat: /etc/lsb-release.d: Is a directory
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
cpe:/o:centos:linux:6:GA

Comment: There isn't a `,` or some other whitespace in your password is there ?

Comment: check your password . for me password was wrong that's why was getting a permission denied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could overcome the error with mount -t cifs ... simply add the parameter `sec=ntlmsspi` to the options. Other possible options are:

```
ntlmssp
ntlmv2
ntlmv2i
```

I was able to create a mount point with `autofs` by following the hint number 4 from [this site](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares)

Some changes needed to be made to `/etc/auto.mymount` The option `sec` must be specified. I found the correct parameters [here](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2011-October/164406.html) (at the very bottom of the page)

My `/etc/auto.mymount` ended up containing one line which is:

```
share -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,user=ESBSertal,pass=MyPassword,domain=ESB,sec=ntlmsspi ://esb.local/dfs
```

executing `service autofs restart` renews the information.

this allowed me to access the contents of the share under `/mnt/win/share`

Comment: Accept this answer as the solution please. I had the same problem on Debian and none of the other parameter naming and domain\username tricks in the other answers solved it. Thanks for it!

Comment: I had the same problem now and it's working with that parameter when i try to mount a Synology drive.

Answer (score 3):

sorry for not asking in a comment, but my rep is not high enough.

Do you have a PDC running on the Windows 2008 server? 
If so you probably missing just the domain for the user

```
 mount.cifs -o user=USER,dom=DOMAIN,password=MYPASS //pdc.domain/test /mnt
```

Have you tried to mount as administrator? If this works, then it's probably only a problem with the share permissions.

Otherwise check the syslog file, it should give you more informations about the error. Possible that the server requires packet signing and your request is without.

Comment: I know the credentials are correct and the servers can communicate, as the smbclient can connect

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't look to be anything inherently wrong with what your doing.

- Check that the username/password etc don't have punctuation/whitespace and if they do put `'` `'` around them.
- Check that the CentOS and Windows firewalls are allow connections (though you'd probably get a different error message for them)

Comment: I know the credentials are correct and the servers can communicate, as the smbclient can connect

Comment: @DrGorb: That's not actually what I said to chcek though.

Comment: what I meant is that the credentials are correct and written correctly and that they are accepted by the Windows server and that the Linux server can send them. If I enter wrong credentials I get the same error though

Comment: @DrGorb: So it won't hurt to put quotes around them just to check will it ?

Comment: tried with single and double quotes: same result

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but instead of CIFS use SMBFS and try to mount your shared partition.

```
  mount -t smbfs //hostname/share /mnt/temp -o username=someuser,password=somepassword
```

Comment: I get mount: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'

Comment: smbfs isn't supported in most new OSs anymore anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command instead:

`mount -t cifs //esb.local/dfs -o username=ESBSertal,password=MyPassword,domain=ESB /mnt/win`

Comment: same result as previous

Answer (score 1):

For RHEL Linux... 
I had to put a couple lines in the /etc/request-key.conf

```
create cifs.spnego * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k


create dns_resolver * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
```

Then mount with this..

```
mount -t cifs //someDFSaddress/somemountcifsexport  /mnt/somemountpoint -o username=somename (enter the passwd manually)
```

Comment: it didn't help with my mount issue but it pointed out a difference in configuration I was not aware of and part of a final solution. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I solved by putting username=domain.local\username in fstab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by first:

```
smbclient -L server_name --user=DOMAIN/user_name -d=10 > output 2>&1
```

then

```
grep -i ntlm output
```

Which had a line that said

```
Got NTLMSSP neg ....
```

I then changed my mount line to be

```
mount -t smbfs //server_name/share_dir /mnt/mount_point -o user=DOMAIN/user_name,sec=ntlmssp
```

FINALLY!

Would like to credit the Dr. Gorb response for leading me to this solution, but don't have enough reputation to add a comment.